# Rails 4 not displaying conditions when uploading images with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, activeadmin

I am doing a website for a PR agency, and they have multiple clients (called cliente). Each of these clients has an image gallery (called cliente_photos) of their own. I am using carrierwave and active_admin to upload through an admin. In the active_admin, I am able to set for with client I want the new uploaded picture to be related with. But on my views, All clients show all images. I assume it is an array conditions problem, but I can't get that to work.

My index view looks like this:

```
 <div class="image-grid mt-60">
     <% Cliente.all.each do |client| %>
        <% client.cliente_photos.each do |photo| %>
           <div class="mb-5 pull-left">
              <%= image_tag photo.imagem.url %>
           </div>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
 </div>
```

When I try to use conditionals like:

```
`<div class="image-grid mt-60">
   <% Cliente.all.each do |client| %>
     <% client.cliente_photos.where("cliente_id = ?", params[:cliente_id]).each do |photo| %>
       <div class="mb-5 pull-left">
          <%= image_tag photo.imagem.url %>
       </div>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>`
```

The images disappear from all clients.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start with `Cliente.all`, you should expect all client images.  If that's not what you wanted, why not filter on the one you *do* want?

```
<div class="image-grid mt-60">
  <% client = Cliente.find(params[:cliente_id]) %>
  <% client.cliente_photos.each do |photo| %>
       <div class="mb-5 pull-left">
          <%= image_tag photo.imagem.url %>
       </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```